# What is a $n_\text{eq} / \text{cm}^{-2}$?

Tags: radiation, units

What is "one neutron equivalent per centimeter squared"? I know it is a measure of accumulated radiation, or similar, but could not find precise definitions in Google.

Comment: Is it still a question? If so, please add some context to the question. (E.g. a reference where they talk about this quantity. Where did you see this?) (Or if you found the answer, you might post that here. So others can find it easier in the future. ;) )

Comment: Yes, it is still a question. I did not found an answer yet. I is not vital knowledge for me, but I would like to know it. The context is in the accumulated radiation of silicon detectors in the LHC.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://indico.cern.ch/event/867956/attachments/1960310/3257733/HL-LHC_specification_document_draft_12_Dec_19.pdf) might help. (The key words were "LHC neutron equivalent".)

From line 175:
Si 1 MeV neutron equivalent (neq) fluence (1MeVn-eq): dedicated variable that quantifies the amount of Displacement Damage (DD) in Silicon, defined as the fluence (i.e.  sum of the track lengths in a given volume divided by the volume itself) of 1-MeV neutrons that produces a DD equivalent to the one of the physical particles, measured in neutrons per cm−2.